# JavaFX - Absolute position in StackPane

Tags: javafx, position

Can I get something like that in a StackPane? I am interested in the second rectangle

I tried to setX and setY to the rectangle, but it still goes to Top left.

[image: Rectangles]

Comment: Use margin/alignment.

Comment: Or just use a `Pane` instead of a `StackPane`

Comment: @James_D I will try to use Pane inseat of StackPane, but I need to align some text to center too. I think I can't Pos.CENTER in Pane.

Comment: Then use a `StackPane` containing the `Pane` (containing the `Rectangle`s) and the `Label`.

Comment: @James_D Tha's not a bad idea. Thanks, I will try it.